# How to change python pocket sphinx dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7, speech-recognition, pocketsphinx

I am trying to make pocketsphinxs live speech recognition more accurate, given that I will only say a couple select words. I searched online and it seems that I should be able to create my own dictionary, using the tool at this website:
http://www.speech.cs.cmu.edu/tools/lmtool-new.html
This seemed to have worked, however I cannot find what to do with the files after I have created them. From the python pocket sphinx website: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pocketsphinx it seems I should be able to set new dictionaries for the live speech recognizer like this:

```
import os
from pocketsphinx import LiveSpeech, get_model_path

model_path = get_model_path()

speech = LiveSpeech(
    verbose=False,
    sampling_rate=16000,
    buffer_size=2048,
    no_search=False,
    full_utt=False,
    hmm=os.path.join(model_path, 'en-us'),
    lm=os.path.join(model_path, 'en-us.lm.bin'),
    dic=os.path.join(model_path, 'cmudict-en-us.dict')
)

for phrase in speech:
    print(phrase)
```

However I am unclear as to what exactly to change in this code to input my own dictionary data. I have tried changing the model_path for the dictionary to the path to the dictionary I downloaded from the website, but that gave an error:

```
RuntimeError: new_Decoder returned -1
```

What do I need to change in this code to get pocketSphinx to use my dictionary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should get something like `8569.lm` - the language model and `8659.dic` - the dictionary. You put them in filesystem and use like this:

```
import os
from pocketsphinx import LiveSpeech, get_model_path

model_path = get_model_path()

speech = LiveSpeech(
    sampling_rate=16000,
    hmm=os.path.join(model_path, 'en-us'),
    lm='/home/user/8569.lm',
    dic='/home/user/8569.dic'
)

for phrase in speech:
    print(phrase)
```

You have to properly specify the filesystem path to the files and it will work.

Comment: This worked and got rid of the error! so thank you, however the program now runs and does nothing, any idea why it would not be returning anything for the text it is supposed to recognize?

Comment: Most likely microphone is muted or does not work, you need to check if you are able to record sound at all.